# Modified Binary Search algorithm exceeding time limit

Tags: c++, binary-search

> You are given a sorted array of numbers, and followed by number of
>   queries, for each query if the queried number is present in the array
>   print its position, else print -1.
>
> Input
>
> First line contains N Q, number of elements in the array and number of
>   queries to follow,
>
> Second line contains N numbers, elements of the array, each number
>   will be -10^9<= ai <= 10^9, 0 < N <= 10^5, 0 < Q <= 5*10^5

Reference:https://www.spoj.com/problems/BSEARCH1/

My code works fine on terminal but it excedes the time limit on the online judge even though it takes O(NQ) time.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

long long binarySearch(long long arr[], long long l , long long r , long long x) {
    long long mid;
    if (r >= l){ 
        mid = (l+r)/2;
        if (arr[mid] == x) {
            if (arr[mid] == arr[mid-1]) {
                while (arr[mid] == arr[mid-1]) {
                    --mid;
                }
                return mid;
            }
            else{
                return mid;
            }
        } 
        if (arr[mid] > x) {
            return  binarySearch(arr,l,mid-1,x);
        } 
        if (arr[mid] < x) {
            return binarySearch(arr,mid+1,r,x);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    long long n ,q;
    std::cin >> n >> q;
    long long array[n];
    for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> array[i];
    }
    long long x;
    long long arr2[q];
    for (long long i = 0 ; i < q ; ++i) {
        std::cin >> x;
        std::cout << binarySearch(array,0,n-1,x) << "\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The time complexity is wrong, it can't be independent on the number of queries Q that are performed.

Comment: Oh I apologise for the mistake.

Comment: @ChiragM I don't think it's O(NQ) though... wouldn't it be O(NQ log N)?

Comment: In the worst case I would have to search the entire array if all the elements are the same.As there are Q queries queries,it becomes O(NQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. You can use the C++ standard library algorithm [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). It does a binary search for the first location where the value could be.

You can rewrite your function as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>

long long binarySearch(long long arr[], long long n, long long x)
{
    // O(log n) binary search for first element not less that x
    long long *itr = std::lower_bound(arr, arr + n, x);

    // If itr is array end or location doesn't contain x
    if (itr == arr + n || *itr != x) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Compute index by address arithmetic
    return itr - arr;
}
```

I've removed one unnecessary function parameter, just pass the array size. By the way, you don't need `long long` for this problem. Might as well use `int` and save some memory.

If you still have timeout problems it might be slow input/output. Try adding the next two lines at the beginning of your `main()`.

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); // possibly faster I/O buffering
std::cin.tie(NULL); // don't flush output stream before doing input
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to print the first position of the found element. However, if you have an array with all elements identical `1,1,1,1,1,1,1`, then you are basically doing `O(n)` for one query, which results in `O(nq)` where n is the length of the array and q the number of queries in the worst case.

Suggestions:
I think what you need to do is to get rid of the duplicates.

1. Sort the array.
2. Create another array of pairs ( like `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>`. With (element, first-pos) as the pair.
3. Then do the binary search on it.

Comment: But I ran in on SPOJ and it says the time limit is exceeded even though linear time shouldnt be a problem here

Comment: I said it becomes nxq which I think is not linear

Comment: I just saw `q` and `n` are both in the order of 10^5. So they won't accept an `O(nq)` solution

Comment: Is there a way to do it using the same aproach?

Comment: But the judge only tests a test case at a time.

Comment: @chiragM one test case contains q queries on an array of size n.

Comment: @ChiragM if you think my answer helped you then please consider upvoting/ accepting the answer. Note that it is not mandatory to do so.

Comment: I appreciate you help but I found @BlastFurnaces more "to the point".

Comment: No problem @ChiragM

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that your implementation of binary search is **recursive**.

I have no idea if the local input data is significantly big to test your implementation is suitable. But if you change the implementation recursive to iterative like [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/), the performance of the code will be enhanced.

The reason why the iterative implementation is better than recursive, check [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56867/why-are-loops-faster-than-recursion).

Note that, with compiler having **tail-call optimization** functionality, the diminish in the speed of recursive implementation could be eliminated.